# What does the word "TBD" means in mpi_get_processor_name function

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, ms-mpi

I was reading the documentation reference about MPI function: **MPI_Get_processor_name(...)** in Microsoft's docs. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473382(v=vs.85).aspx

And I found The word "**TBD**" replaces every Explanation to be expected about the purpose of the function or the parameters.

Does it mean "To Be Deleted" or "To Be Defined" or ... ? 
Thx in advance;

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TBD

Comment: Thank you @andreee : I did really read Wikipedia's article about it.

Comment: Thank you @andreee : I did really read Wikipedia's article about it.
But the Idea is that this function is not some sort of a new technique to use or whatever! afaik,, and it appears that  "To Be Deleted"  is more conceiving in such a way.
And If that so,, Do I have to use it? or use something else...

Answer (score 0):

TBD: To Be Determined (that basically means not yet documented)